# Remover acentos com lua

Tags: lua

Alguém poderia dar um exemple de como faço para remover acentos de palavras com LUA.
EX: função => funcao,
manhã  => manha

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar a biblioteca "stringx" para remover acentos de palavras com LUA. Abaixo esta um exemplo de como usar a funcao "unaccent" desta biblioteca para remover acentos de uma string:

```
local stringx = require "pl.stringx"
local str_com_acento = "manhã"
local str_sem_acento = stringx.unaccent(str_com_acento)
print(str_sem_acento) -- imprime "manha"
```

Note que voce precisara ter a biblioteca "**stringx**" instalada em seu sistema para poder usar essa funcao.